# What is a speed for compiling any program in Command prompt

Tags: command-prompt

I create one program in java but that program just like loop program but once I run that program I face program is gone in infinity so I arise that question is what actual speed of the command prompt for running any program.

I can run many java programs in the infinity loop.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Patternchar
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {   
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num = sc.nextInt();
           for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
           {
            for(int j=num;j>=i;j--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(i);
            for(int k = i-1;k>=1;k--)
            {
                System.out.print(" 1");
                if(num == 15)
                {
                    for(int y=15;y>=1;y--)
                    {
                        System.out.print(15-y);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print(" "+i);
            System.out.println();
           }
        }
    }
```

Type the num = 1224

That program goes to the infinity loop

Comment: I’m not clear what the question is here? Is this a homework question? It seems like a bizarre program to write.

Comment: In that case, I asked about what actual speed of command prompt when we run a java program. when any java program got the infinite mode that's case command prompt gate a much more time so I have known about what actual speed of command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing to point out is that it’s not an infinite loop. Which is a shame because that would make it easy to answer. An infinite loop would take an infinite amount of time to execute, no matter what hardware you run it on.

I think what you’re actually asking is, Why does it take so long to run? We can’t say how long it will take to run because you don’t say what computer you’re using. I *guess* you’re using Windows because you talk about a “command prompt.”

But, I think your problem is that you’re outputting to the screen. Writing to the screen is generally pretty slow, but especially so in Windows. Try redirecting the output to a file instead and it’ll be a lot faster.

For comparison, it runs in under thirty seconds on a Raspberry Pi Zero when writing to a “file.”

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ time java Patternchar > /dev/null

real    0m24.491s
user    0m21.342s
sys     0m2.428s
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I think its most useful for me. also, check out my other problem I think you can solve my questions